# Perform group by average without grouping rows into a single output row in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to perform the equivalent of postgreSQL'a WINDOW function in pandas. Basically, I want to average column values in a specific group and create a new column with the results without grouping the rows into a single output row.

Here's an example:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(
'name': ['Steve', 'Jim', 'Anna', 'Susie', 'Greg', 'John', 'Sabrina'],
'salary': [100, 200, 300, 100, 250, 90, 260],
'department': ['Finance', 'Finance', 'HR', 'Finance', 'Operations', 'HR', 
'Operations']
})
```

I can group by and average the salaries with

```
data.groupby('department').agg('mean')
```

and then left merge the results with the original data.

The final result should have all the all the rows and columns 'name', 'department' and 'avg salary by department'.

I'm wondering if there is a quicker and more elegant way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html)

```
df['Mean']=df.groupby('department').transform('mean')
df
Out[656]: 
   department     name  salary        Mean
0     Finance    Steve     100  133.333333
1     Finance      Jim     200  133.333333
2          HR     Anna     300  195.000000
3     Finance    Susie     100  133.333333
4  Operations     Greg     250  255.000000
5          HR     John      90  195.000000
6  Operations  Sabrina     260  255.000000
```

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot!